# Is it possible to create a .ISO or .IMG of my smartphone and emulate it in a Android Emulator?

Tags: android-emulator

I have a Moto G6 running Android 9. I would like to generate a ISO or IMG of my smartphone and load it by using a Android Emulator in a computer. Is that possible?

Comment: Android firmware is device specific and needs to be adapted to the hardware. For an emulator you need an image that has been created for the Android emulator.

Comment: @Robert I think that's a good answer! How about copy and paste it as an answer?